# How to pattern match on input tuples ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, tuples, ocaml

For example, I have the code

```
let add_next (data: int * int * int list) : int =
```

However,the word data is really ambiguous, and I'd like to be able to name the first two integers and then the list in the function header, while preserving the type of `int * int * int list`.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OCaml version 4.01.0

#  let add_next ((first, second, l): int * int * int list) : int = first;;
val add_next : int * int * int list -> int = <fun>
```

If you need to pass the `data` tuple around without having to rebuild it, use the `as` construct:

```
# let add_next ((first, second, l) as data: int * int * int list) : int =
    ignore data;
    first;;
val add_next : int * int * int list -> int = <fun>
```